# How we can redirect back to home page after logout with Instagram API

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using Instagram API for login with Instagram without Signup.The issue is that how I can log out from Instagram from my website and redirect back to my website home page. If I will use this link as a href in Log out button https://instagram.com/accounts/logout then Instagram will be logged out but How I will redirect back to my website home page. I m also using Facebook API for login and its provide me logout URL, when I will click on it then it will log out facebook account and then after this, it redirects back to my website homepage.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

instead of opening the logout URL, use javascript to append an hidden iframe with logout URL:

```
$(document).append('<div style="display:none"><iframe src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0"></iframe></div>');
```

this will logout of instagram and then show login button.

Comment: This likely won't work as X-Frame-Options policy for 'https://www.instagram.com/' is 'SAMEORIGIN'.